# Unity 3D EveryPlay Check if video has been uploaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, everyplay

How do I find out if a user uploads a video with `EveryPlay`?

```
if (Everyplay.SharedInstance.UploadDidComplete())
{
   ...
```

Is this correct?

```
#pragma strict
// JavaScript

function Start () {
Everyplay.SharedInstance.UploadDidComplete +=  UploadDidCompleteDelegate(int videoId);
}

function UploadDidComplete () {
// upload successful
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use C# instead.

```
void Start() {
    Everyplay.SharedInstance.UploadDidComplete += UploadDidComplete;
}

void Destroy() {
    if(Everyplay.SharedInstance != null) {
        Everyplay.SharedInstance.UploadDidComplete -= UploadDidComplete;
    }
}

private void UploadDidComplete(int videoId) {
    // Upload did complete
}
```

Comment: I just submitted my app to apple and got rejected for giving coins for sharing videos. So just a heads up it is not allowed on ios per 
3.10

We still found that your app, or its metadata, includes features or content that can have an excessive influence in the listing order or ranking on the App Store, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, we found your app prompts users to share the app on social media to receive coins.